# Lua french locale failed

Tags: lua, locale

I tried this code :

```
assert(os.setlocale('fr_FR'))
print(12.34)
```

And it failed.

```
locale.lua 
lua: locale.lua:1: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    locale.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

On Ubuntu 14.04, lua -v

```
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Comment: Do you have the `fr_FR` locale available? Does `locale -a | grep fr_FR` output anything?

Comment: Use `assert(os.setlocale('fr_FR.utf8'))`

Comment: I did. It works. Feel free to write an answer. Thank you.